# Prove that $F[a]$ is a field if and only if $a$ is algebraic over $F$

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory

This is really just a yes/no question, but I need to make sure that I am right about the following:

If $\alpha$ is algebraic over $F$, then $F[\alpha]$ is a field. To show this, I let $f(x)$ be the minimal polynomial for $F$ for $\alpha$ over $F$. Then the ideal generated by $f$ is maximal. Then one can show that there is an isomorphism between
$$
F[x] / \langle f(x)\rangle
$$
and
$$
F[\alpha].
$$
And this shows that $F[\alpha]$ is a field.

Is this a correct way to do this?

How might I prove that $F[\beta]$ is a field only if $\beta$ is algebraic over $F$?

Comment: What about the [perplex numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Split-complex_number) $\mathbb R[j]$ with $j^2-1=0$? That's certainly not a field.

Comment: @mr_e_man: Is $j$ algebraic over $\mathbb{R}$?

Comment: $j$ satisfies a polynomial equation with coefficients in $\mathbb R$; I thought that was the _definition_ of "algebraic over $\mathbb R$". But I guess your question was about "algebraic field extensions" so that $\alpha$ is assumed to be contained in a larger field. $j$ is not in any field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you are correct that that is a way to show $F[\alpha]$ is a field. To show that $F[\beta]$ is a field implies $\beta$ is algebraic, note that $\frac{1}{\beta}$ must be in $F[\beta]$, and thus is a polynomial in $\beta$. What can you do from here?

Answer (score 2):

If it's a field you must have an equation  of the form
$$\frac{1}{a}=c_0+\cdots +c_na^n$$