# If $\mathbb Q[a,b]$ is a field, then are $a$ and $b$ algebraic?

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

I have some difficulties in solving the following problem:

If $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha, \beta]$ is a field, then are $\alpha, \beta$ algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$?

It is likely to be true in my thought, but I have some difficulties in proving. Can anybody help me..?

Comment: Hint: look up Zariski’s lemma.

Comment: If $\alpha,\beta$ are not algebraic over $\mathbf{Q}$, then you have an isomorphism $\mathbf{Q}[\alpha,\beta] \xrightarrow[]{} \mathbf{Q}[x,y]$ (perhaps a bit over the top).

Comment: What have you tried? For one variable see [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1930594/prove-that-fa-is-a-field-if-and-only-if-a-is-algebraic-over-f).

Comment: @MarianoSuárez-Álvarez I know how to do when only $alpha$ appears. But how can I extend to more than one variables?

Comment: @Aphelli I've never heard that. Isn't there any elementary metholds?

Comment: @DietrichBurde I know how to do when only $\alpha$
 appears. But how can I extend to more than one variables?

Comment: You can write $\Bbb Q(\alpha,\beta)=\Bbb Q(\alpha)(\beta)$ and thus reduce it to the case you already know.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Since $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha][\beta]$ is a field, by the single variable case, $\beta$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$. Since $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha]$ is a field, $\alpha$ is algebraic over $\mathbb{Q}$. And $\beta$ is algebraic over Q. Am I right then?

Comment: If $\mathbb{Q}[\alpha,\beta]$ is a field, then it is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ by Zariski's lemma. In particular, it is an algebraic extension which shows that both $\alpha,\beta$ are algebraic.

Comment: @DietrichBurde Well, I think that then Zariski's Lemma proof would be trivial, but it isn't.

Comment: @AntonOdina $X$ and $X^2$ are not algebraic over any field $k$. However $k[X,X^2]$ is not isomorphic to $k[X,Y]$.